# monitor connected to vga connector not showing native resolution with AMD graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, vga, amd-graphics-card

I have a three monitor setup

1. 1920x1200 - connected to display port
2. 1920x1200 - connected to display port
3. 1920x1200 - connected to vga

The monitor connected to vga goes down to 1920x1080 and the display doesnot look as good.

Its not monitor issue, since when i connected DisplayPort to the affecter monitor, it shows up correctly native resolution.

I have another monitor at home which is 1680x1050 and that monitor shows up the native resolution when connected to vga port in a 3-display setup.

SO, either

1. VGA does not support above 1920x1080. But my docking station has only two display ports and one vga.
   OR
2. I need to updated display driver.

I tried doing #2, it keeps saying I have the latest one. How to fix this issue? All the monitors support dvi/vga/displayport and the docking station only supports displayport(2) and 1 vga.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standards for maximum VGA standards, because its an analogue connection. Better connections, better cable quality, shorter cables can all help.

VGA was invented in 1987.

Wikipedia claims that 2048×1536@85 Hz is achievable - although it seems unlikely...

Answer (score 0):

VGA will support the higher resolution, but the graphics card in your laptop may not.

In Windows 7 rt click on background and select "Screen Resolution".  T
Here click on the monitor in question and select Advanced Settings.  This will pull up the device properties for your graphics card.
Under the Adapter tab, click on "List All Modes".  This will show a list of all resolutions, color depth and refresh rates supported by the graphics card for the monitor you selected.  In there, you can try to force a specific resolution and refresh.

In most cases, graphics cards will support any higher resolition, but only at lower refresh rates.  Give a few of them a try and see if you can find one you like.

I'm sure there's a similar way to do it in Windows 10, but I'm not that familiar with it yet.

If that fails, another thing you can look at is whether or not any of your Display Port monitors support daisy chaining.  If so, that would free up a display port port.

See (https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln293813/how-to-daisy-chain-multiple-monitors-using-displayport-multi-stream-transport-mst) for more info.